# Hide specific fieldset class with css

Tags: html, css, shopify, fieldset

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgcIE.png)

```html
<variant-radios id="variant-radios-template--17912133255436__main" class="no-js-hidden" data-section="template--17912133255436__main" data-url="y">
<fieldset class="js product-form__input">
          <legend class="form__label">A</legend>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="js product-form__input">
          <legend class="form__label">B</legend>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="js product-form__input">
          <legend class="form__label">C</legend>
</fieldset>
</variant-radios>
```

I want to hide 2 of these 3 fieldset classes via css.

F.e. hide "A" and "B", but "C" remains visible

How?

I can hide all with:

```html
#variant-radios-template--17912133255436__main{
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!, Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour), and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), the [perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/) and how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: As well as following the advice given by @disinfor, could you describe exactly what you mean by 'two of these three fieldset classes'. Do you mean that you have three fieldset elements and you want to hide two of them or ...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nth-child in CSS to reference which fieldsets that you would like to hide.

```css
fieldset.js.product-form__input:nth-child(1),
fieldset.js.product-form__input:nth-child(2){
 display:none;
}
```

```html
<variant-radios id="variant-radios-template--17912133255436__main" class="no-js-hidden" data-section="template--17912133255436__main" data-url="y">
<fieldset class="js product-form__input">
          <legend class="form__label">A</legend>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="js product-form__input">
          <legend class="form__label">B</legend>
</fieldset>
<fieldset class="js product-form__input">
          <legend class="form__label">C</legend>
</fieldset>
</variant-radios>
```